# Storyline involving killer robots that harvest legs

Tags: story-identification, movie

Hoping someone can identify this episode or movie I saw in the late 80s or early 90s.

A group of 5-10 people, males and females, are trapped inside a large ship (or bunker, or something).  Inside with them are 2-3 killer robots.  The robots roll around on wheels, are about 4 feet tall and are white. I remember thinking they looked like sleek, futuristic dumpsters - the small 2-yard dumpsters you see in narrow alleyways in some cities.
When the robots catch and kill someone, it appears that they harvest their legs, for lack of a better description.  For the rest of the film/episode after a kill, the robot rolls around with one leg from each of its victims sticking out of the top of it, foot pointing upward.

It has the feel of a British sci-fi, but I'm not sure whether it's actually British.  The sets remind me of the later seasons of Red Dwarf: very dark and industrial, a lot of pipes and metal grating, red and yellow background lighting.

I also seem to recall one of the women of the group being dressed in very gaudy 80s dance-club style attire.  I'm pretty sure she was rocking a pink boa.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Longshot, but this sounds a bit like ["Paradise Towers"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paradise_Towers), an episode of *Doctor Who* from 1987. The episode itself takes place in a run-down apartment tower, which has turned into a kind of dystopian micro-nation.

The primary antagonists, at least for a while, are the Cleaners, white robots who have developed a bit of a taste for human flesh:

[image]

Note the dumpster-like thing dragging behind; every time a Cleaner kills someone, we're treated to a shot of one of those bins trundling off, with a foot sticking out the top:

[image]

<sup>Thanks to Mr. Lister for the screenshot</sup>

Despite the setting being an apartment building, many scenes look very industrial; the lair of the Kangs, a gang of teenaged girls stirring up trouble, is essentially a concrete bunker:

[image]

And parts of the set, particularly the basement (where the *real* Big Bad is hiding) is rather more industrial-looking.

Can't help you with the pink boa, though. However, as Mr. Lister reminds me in comments, some of the Kangs wore red scarves:

[image]

<sup>Thanks to Mr. Lister for this screenshot, too</sup>

Comment: Oh man, that looks familiar!  Going to have to watch it, but going to mark this answered.  Many thanks!
Also, not sure where I got the boa either.  Brain filling in details with utter fiction, I suppose.

Comment: @user1103 Really? I was not expecting this to actually be it... Oh well, glad to help

Comment: [Here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/3LqFh.jpg) is the back of a bin with a leg sticking out. As for the boas, some of the characters have red scarves. [Here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/sYyZX.jpg).

Comment: Yep, definitely it.  Looking at screenshots, remembering the red girls and the blue girls (Kangs, apparently).  Had a feeling it might be a Dr. Who, but there's so much of it and, strangely, I don't seem to know any hardcore DW fans.

Comment: @MrLister Thanks for the screens!